# How do I get MELPA working on my Windows 8 laptop

Tags: package-repositories

In my init file `~\AppData\Roaming\.emacs.d` that I created using `C-x C-f ~/.emacs.d/init.el RET`
I tried:

```
(require 'package) ;; You might already have this line
(add-to-list 'package-archives
             '("melpa" . "https://melpa.org/packages/"))
(when (< emacs-major-version 24)
  ;; For important compatibility libraries like cl-lib
  (add-to-list 'package-archives '("gnu" . "http://elpa.gnu.org/packages/")))
(package-initialize) ;; You might already have this line
```

and

```
(setq package-archives '(("gnu" . "https://elpa.gnu.org/packages/")
                         ("marmalade" . "https://marmalade-repo.org/packages/")
                         ("melpa" . "https://melpa.org/packages/")))
```

and

```
(add-to-list 'package-archives '("marmalade" . "https://marmalade-repo.org/packages/"))
(add-to-list 'package-archives '("melpa" . "https://melpa.org/packages/"))
(add-to-list 'package-archives '("org" . "http://orgmode.org/elpa/") t) ; Org-mode's repository
```

using both https:// and http:// [since the Melpa website states there are issues with windows and https](https://melpa.org/#/getting-started)

Each time I have edited and saved the file and afterwards (re-)started Emacs.
Still after `C-x list-packages RET` I seem to get the ELPA list only.

I'd really appreciate some help, because I have no idea what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Cf6tRBPbWKs) gave me the clue to solve my problem:

```
M-x customize-group RET package RET
```

Expand "Package Archives" then INS

Fill in:

Archive Name: `melpa`

and URL or directory name: `http://melpa.org/packages/`

Apply and Save

(https didn't work)

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend for Windows (as long as you have 64-bit) downloading the [emacs-w64](https://sourceforge.net/projects/emacsbinw64/) distribution as it comes bundled with all of the extra libraries you need to make things like ssl and images work.  Failing that, you can download the latest in `gnutls` [here](ftp://ftp.gnutls.org/gcrypt/gnutls/w3) and place the contents of the `/bin` directory in the same folder as `emacs.exe`.

Comment: Sounds useful, but I don't think it speaks to the question.

Comment: Perhaps, but I haven't had any HTTPS issues on Windows since downloading the emacs-w64 builds.

Comment: It wasn't the https issues, it was the fact that emacs wasn't even trying to connect.

Answer (score 0):

Since you mentioned you can accept http connection without security concern,

```
(setq package-archives
        '(("gnu" . "http://elpa.gnu.org/packages/")
          ("melpa-stable" . "http://stable.melpa.org/packages/")
          ("org" . "http://orgmode.org/elpa/")))
```

Comment: As I stated in my original post, I tried adding that block of code using both http and https